# Pandas dataframe from list, specifying header separately

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
data = [
    (132603, 'TV Series', 'hbo', 'Chris Rock', datetime.date(2008, 9, 2), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 6, 2, 16)), 
    (132605, 'TV Series', 'madman', 'Joanna Lumley', datetime.date(2012, 10, 24), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 16, 45))
]
```

And I create a dataframe as follows:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data)

        0          1       2              3           4                   5
0  132603  TV Series     hbo     Chris Rock  2008-09-02 2019-02-06 02:16:00
1  132605  TV Series  madman  Joanna Lumley  2012-10-24 2019-02-05 16:45:00
```

How would I specify a headers column when creating the dataframe, such as:

```
pd.DataFrame(data, headers=['id', 'type','network','start','end'])
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'type','network','missing_column','start','end'])` your list of headers has 5 entries whereas your data has 6 headers. fix that and use this syntax

Comment: Try to at least glance at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the fine [manual page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), you'll find that `columns=` does what you want.